# How to return both png and html in scrapy-splash?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

If I had a html and png returned from a scrapy-splash request, how to I use that html to scrape an element while also using the png to save a png image?

Do I write response.html and response.png?

Answer (score 0):

SplashJsonResponse is returned when the result is a JSON object. In your case, to access png image you can use `response.data['png']`